# Structured bindings for your own type that isn’t a struct or a tuple(via public member function)

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple, structured-bindings, if-constexpr

I am going through the Herb Sutter's

**A journey: Toward more powerful and simpler C++ programming**

[Structure Binding](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708213601/https://herbsutter.com/2016/06/30/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-oulu/) section

In order to understand the concept .Best is to write a program I tried but getting some error

> Just want to try how to use structure binding on class with private
>   data .Please ignore the below example.if any example you can provide

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class foobar {
public:
    foobar() { cout << "foobar::foobar()\n"; }
    ~foobar() { cout << "foobar::~foobar()\n"; }

    foobar( const foobar &rhs )
    { cout << "foobar::foobar( const foobar & )\n"; }
    void ival( int nval, string new_string ) { _ival = nval;s=new_string; }

private:
    int _ival;
    string s;
};

foobar f( int val,string new_string ) {
    foobar local;
    local.ival( val,new_string );
    return local;
}

template<> struct tuple_element<0,foobar> { using type = int; };
template<> struct tuple_element<1,foobar> { using type = string; };



 // 2. Now add get<> support (using C++17, because why not; it’s better
 // than =delete’ing the primary get<> template and adding specializations)
 template<int I>
 auto get(const foobar&x) {
 if      constexpr(I == 0) return x._ival;//'_ival' is a private member of 'foobar'
 else if constexpr(I == 1) return x.s;//'s' is a private member of 'foobar'
 }


int main(){
    foobar ml = f( 1024,"hello" );
    auto [ n, s] = f( 1024,"hello" );//Cannot decompose non-public member '_ival' o
    return 0;
}
```

Error

> if      constexpr(I == 0) return x._ival;//'_ival' is a private member
>   of 'foobar'
>
> else if constexpr(I == 1) return x.s;//'s' is a private member of 'foobar'
>
> auto [ n, s] = f( 1024,"hello" );//Cannot decompose non-public

**Help required**

1.If anyone can elaborate what he is actually trying to do on these lines 
(please refer the link provided)

```
// 2. Now add get<> support (using C++17, because why not; it’s better
// than =delete’ing the primary get<> template and adding specializations)
template<int I>
auto get(const S&) {
   if      constexpr(I == 0) return x.i;
   else if constexpr(I == 1) return string_view{x.c}; }
   else if constexpr(I == 2) return x.d;
}
```

2.Any suggestion how to fix the error for the above example

Comment: Just want to try how to use structure binding on class with private data

Comment: Well, the error seems pretty self-explanatory: a non-member non-friend function `get` is trying to access private members of a class.

Comment: First of all, don't edit answers into your questions. Second of, einpoklum didn't suggest those changes, I did.

Comment: @Barry sorry for that would you like to add the full answer post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Fixing the errors in Sutter's example

I think it's a typo/glitch in Herb Sutter's blog post: He should have made those members public, or provided getters for them, or made the `std::get()` function a friend.

Also, it looks like Herb forgot to put "x" in the function signature...

#### Explanation of the get function

The function you quote is similar to how `std::get()` works for tuples. If I have

```
std::tuple<int, std::string> t;
```

then

```
auto x { std::get<0>(t) }; // x is an integer
auto y { std::get<1>(t) }; // y is an std::string
```

and in Herb's example, he needs to have the same work for the `S` class, i.e. have `std::get<0>(s)` return the first member of `s`, `std::get<1>(s)` return the second member etc. This is necessary, because otherwise, you can't use `S` for initializing a structured binding.

The "magic" in Hebr's implementation is that he's returning values of different types from different points in his function. This "magic" is the effect of an `if constexpr`. It means, essentially, that the compiler ignores everything except the syntax of the irrelevant branches. So for `I = 0`, the function is:

```
auto get(const S&) {
  if (true) return x.i;
  /* else if constexpr(I == 1) return string_view{x.c}; 
     else if constexpr(I == 2) return x.d;
   */
}
```

for `I = 1` it's

```
template<int I>
auto get(const S&) {
   if      (false) {/* return x.i; */ ; }
   else if (true) return string_view{x.c};
   /* else if constexpr(I == 2) return x.d; */
   }
}
```

etc. And the `auto` chooses the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion by making the get function a public function .I still see issue with  auto [ n, s] = f( 1024,"hello" ); Anything I need to change here

Answer (score 16):

There are many problems here.

First, in order to qualify for structured bindings, you need to specialize `tuple_size`:

```
namespace std {
    template <> struct tuple_size<foobar> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 2> { };
}
```

Next, your specializations of `tuple_element` also have to be in `namespace std`:

```
namespace std {
    template <> struct tuple_size<foobar> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 2> { };

    template <> struct tuple_element<0,foobar> { using type = int; };
    template <> struct tuple_element<1,foobar> { using type = std::string; };
}
```

Next, your `get` must be declared as a `friend` function if you're going to access private members, as per usual:

```
class foobar {
    template <int I> friend auto get(foobar const& );
};
```

Lastly, `get()` really had better return references, otherwise your bindings will end up doing surprising things:

```
template<int I>
auto const& get(const foobar&x) {
    if      constexpr(I == 0) return x._ival;
    else if constexpr(I == 1) return x.s;
}
```

Rather than dealing with `friend`ship, it's easier to just make `get()` a public member, and then write the three overloads you need:

```
class foobar {
public:
    template <size_t I>
    auto& get() & {
        if constexpr (I == 0) return _ival;
        else if constexpr (I == 1) return s;
    }

    template <size_t I>
    auto const& get() const& {
        if constexpr (I == 0) return _ival;
        else if constexpr (I == 1) return s;
    }

    template <size_t I>
    auto&& get() && {
        if constexpr (I == 0) return std::move(_ival);
        else if constexpr (I == 1) return std::move(s);
    }
};
```

---

Also `ival()` as a function doesn't make sense. Your constructor should just take arguments.

Comment: Did all the changes but I am getting error Call to 'get' is ambiguous at  auto [n, s] = f( 1024,"hello" );

Comment: @HariomSingh You need another overload of `get()` to return rvalue references.

Comment: @Barry Can/should an `std::get` be a part of this? Isn't it more common for a user to expect that? After all, `std::tuple` has no `get` method.

Comment: @user2023370 No, it should not. `std::tuple` is in `std` so it can have `std::get`, but your tuple-like thing is _not_ in `std`, so it should not.

Comment: I'm happy to go with that, but can I ask about your reasoning? `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` are also both in `std`. Yes, `std::get` is an overload, which is different, but do you have an instinct for that distinction? I don't see that as obvious. Perhaps it's simply specified that way. Secondly, from a generic programming perspective, I would find it convenient if `std::get` (like `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element`) would work for both my own tuple-like objects, as well as `std::tuple`.

Comment: @user2023370 Yes, but `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` are class templates - they _have_ to be specialized in `std`. But nothing about `std::get` suggests its intended to be a customization point. You can't rely on any kind of `get` in generic code, since structured bindings allows them as members anyway.

Comment: Happy days: I've just come across [P0846](https://wg21.link/P0846) which allows ADL for templates in C++20, and so the correct `get` can be found.

Comment: @Barry You mentioned three different overloads for the get member function, i.e. `&`, `const&`, `&&`. Did you leave out the 4th one on purpose? I.e. `auto&& get() const &&`? I believe it should be included as you would end up with a dangling reference otherwise?