# Can can I make `std::ranges::views::elements` work with a range of my type

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Consider a `Point` type with `x`, `y` and `z` values. If I have a range of `Point` objects, such as `std::vector<Point>`, what do I need to add to `Point` to make it work with the `std::ranges::views::elements` range adaptor?

The intention is to do something like

```cpp
std::vector<Point> v{...};
for (auto x : v | std::ranges::views::elements<0>) {
    // do something with all `x` values
}
```

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/elements_view) mentions that `std::ranges::views::elements` works with "tuple-like" values. I have assumed that it should work similarly to how we can make our type [work with structured binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898828/structured-bindings-for-your-own-type-that-isn-t-a-struct-or-a-tuplevia-public), but I seem to be missing something

I have tried with the following code

```cpp
class Point {
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    double z=0;
public:
    Point(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    template <std::size_t N>
    double get() const {
        if constexpr(N == 0)
            return x;
        else if constexpr(N == 1)
            return y;
        else if constexpr(N == 2)
            return z;
    }
};

namespace std {

template <>
struct tuple_size<Point> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 3> {};

template <std::size_t N>
struct tuple_element<N, Point> {
    using type = double;
};
}
```

This is enough to make structured binding work, but `std::ranges::views::elements` still does not work. Then I thought that maybe `std::ranges::views::elements` needed `std::get<n>(p)` to work and I added a specialization below to the `std` namespace

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
double get(const Point &p) {
    if constexpr(N == 0)
        return p.get<0>();
    else if constexpr(N==1)
        return p.get<1>();
    else if constexpr(N==2)
        return p.get<2>();
}
```

Now it is possible to use std::get<0>(p) to extract the `x` value, but again this is not enough for `std::ranges::views::elements`. What else is necessary to make a range of `Point` objects work with `std::ranges::views::elements`?

---

PS: I know I could just use a `views::transform` here, but my main intention here it to be generic and to understand how these things are suppose to fit together.generic and to understant how these things are supose to fit together.

Comment: Can you provide the error message you get?

Comment: The alternative is to provide a member function to convert `Point` into a `tuple` containing references to its members, https://godbolt.org/z/Kxnsdn1bM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can can I make `std::ranges::views::elements` work with a range of my type

No, you can't<sup>†</sup>.

The way that `elements` is specified, in [[range.elements.view]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.elements.view), it's constrained on:

```cpp
  template<class T, size_t N>
  concept has-tuple-element =                   // exposition only
    requires(T t) {
      typename tuple_size<T>::type;
      requires N < tuple_size_v<T>;
      typename tuple_element_t<N, T>;
      { get<N>(t) } -> convertible_­to<const tuple_element_t<N, T>&>;
    };
```

but we have to keep in mind the general rule in the library, from [[contents]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#contents-3) that:

> Whenever a name `x` defined in the standard library is mentioned, the name `x` is assumed to be fully qualified as​ `::​std​::​`x, unless explicitly described otherwise. For example, if the *Effects*: element for library function `F` is described as calling library function `G`, the function​ `::​std​::​G` is meant.

The `get<N>(t)` there is not an unqualified call to `get`, it's a call to `::std::get<N>(t)` (there is no "unless explicitly described otherwise").

What that means is that this is testing `std::get<0>` (for `keys`), and that's not going to find user-provided structured bindings support (which should either be a member `e.get<0>()` or an unqualified `get<0>(e)` in the associated namespace). You can't just add overloads into `std` to make this work.

So... not currently supported.

---

<sup>†</sup>Technically, if you stick your overload of `std::get<N>(Point)` into namespace `std` and ensure that it is defined *before* `<ranges>` is included, this will Just Work<sup>TM</sup>. But this is highly fragile, both because you have to carefully control the include order (which you can't really do) and involves adding overloads into `std` (which you also shouldn't do either, especially in this case where those overloads wouldn't help structured bindings anyway).

Comment: I thought of this, but it seemed so obviously useful a feature to omit that I assumed it to be a defect!  I can’t find any discussion of the restriction, which seems to ultimately date back to [the second revision of P0789](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0789r1.pdf) which lamentably contains absolutely no explanation of anything.

Comment: @DavisHerring `elements` was added by P1035, but the issue here is that there is no library protocol for tuple-like... so it just only supports the library tuples. Plus ADL `get` is just... a problem.

Comment: I checked with the "fragile solution" and It works exactly as you mentioned. But indeed it is very fragile. For now I'll just use views::transform whenever I need it, instead of making my `Point` type work with the generic `views::elements`.

Answer (score 0):

The intent is that you provide a non-member `get` function template in **your** namespace (for ADL).  This *is* more strict than structured bindings, which support member `get` as well.

Your specialization didn’t work because it’s not a specialization: it’s an **overload** and is thus disallowed in namespace `std` (and in practice wasn’t found by name lookup from within `<ranges>`).

Comment: I also tried with a non-member `get` function, but it didn't work. It seems that @Barry's answer is correct and the call to `get<N>(Point)` is qualified with `std::`, which thus does not allow for ADL to find my non-member `get` implementation.